# 要素の合計が期待している数値と少し違う

Tags: c

データの個数を入力させ、その入力した要素全てと、その要素の合計を出力するプログラムを作成したいのですが、要素の合計が期待している数値と少し違います。
私は以下のようにプログラムしました。

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* size個 の入力された実数データを 配列の先頭から順番に格納する */
void readDoubleArray(double a[], int size)
{
int i;
for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1) {
        printf("%d 番目? ", i+1);
        scanf("%lf", &a[i]);
}
}

/* size個 の実数データが入っている配列を 配列の先頭から順に出力する */
void printDoubleArray(double a[], int size)
{
int i;
for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1) {
        printf("%lf ", a[i]);
}
    printf("\n");
}

//要素数size の合計値を返す．

double souwa(double a[], int size)
{
int i;
double s;
s=1;
for(i=1;i<size;i=i+1) {
s=s+a[i];
}
return s;

}


int main(void)
{
    double data[1024];
    int size;

    printf("データの個数を入力してください：");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    readDoubleArray(data, size);
    printf("順番に出力:");
    printDoubleArray(data, size);
    printf("合計:%lf\n", souwa(data,size));
      
    return 0;
}
```

実行結果

```
$ ./a.out
データの個数を入力してください： 4
1 番目? 2
2 番目? 4
3 番目? 6
4 番目? 8
順番に出力:2.000000 4.000000 6.000000 8.000000 
合計:19.000000
```

期待している実行結果

```
$ ./a.out
データの個数を入力してください： 4
1 番目? 2
2 番目? 4
3 番目? 6
4 番目? 8
順番に出力:2.000000 4.000000 6.000000 8.000000 
合計:20.000000
```

どこが間違っているのでしょうか。ご回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

関数`souwa`の中に二か所間違いがあります。
一つは、合計を入れる変数`s`を1で初期化していることです。ここは0でなければなりません。
もう一つは、`for`内のインデックスを1から始めていることです。

結果的に、初期値の1に、配列の二番目から最後までを合計していて、

```
1 + 4 + 6 + 8 = 19
```

になっています。正しくは

```
double souwa(double a[], int size)
{
    int i;
    double s;
    s=0.0; // ここ
    for(/*ここ*/i=0;i<size;i=i+1) {
        s=s+a[i];
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。s=1としていたので間違っていたのですね。ご指摘どおりにs=0.0と初期値を設定し直したら期待したコンパイル結果が出力されました。